# Multiple user inputs Python GUI using Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Below is a simplified version of the Python code I am writing. The code uses Tkinter to generate a GUI which takes multiple user inputs, for later processing.

The issue I am having is the function `get_user_input()` only returns the user input from the final line of the user input. How can I re-write this function to return all the user inputs into a Dict or DataFrame?

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

window = tk.Tk()
window.title("User Input Window")

input_labels = ["Runner", "Course", "Start time","Finish time"]
for i, label in enumerate(input_labels):
    ttk.Label(window, text=label).grid(row=0, column=i, padx=10, pady=5, sticky='s')

def get_user_input():
    print(f"{runner_entry.get()},{course_entry.get()},{start_time_entry.get()},{finish_time_entry.get()}")

for row in range(1, 10):
    runner_var = tk.StringVar()
    runner_entry = ttk.Entry(window)
    runner_entry.grid(row=row, column=0, padx=10, pady=5)

    course_var = tk.StringVar()
    course_entry = ttk.Entry(window)
    course_entry.grid(row=row, column=1, padx=10, pady=5)

    start_time_var = tk.StringVar()
    start_time_entry = ttk.Entry(window)
    start_time_entry.grid(row=row, column=2, padx=10, pady=5)

    finish_time_var = tk.StringVar()
    finish_time_entry = ttk.Entry(window)
    finish_time_entry.grid(row=row, column=3, padx=10, pady=5)

submit_button = tk.Button(window, text="Submit", command=get_user_input)
submit_button.grid(row=14, column=0, columnspan=2, pady=10)

window.mainloop()
```

[image: Screenshot of the Tkinter GUI]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

so you are actually creating multiple entries of a same variables so if you need to store the data you will need to differentiate and store them separately or crate a dict. or list and store the data within:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

window = tk.Tk()
window.title("User Input Window")

input_labels = ["Runner", "Course", "Start time", "Finish time"]
for i, label in enumerate(input_labels):
    ttk.Label(window, text=label).grid(row=0, column=i, padx=10, pady=5, sticky='s')

entries = {'runner': [], 'course': [], 'start_time': [], 'finish_time': []}

def get_user_input():
    for row in range(len(entries['runner'])):
        runner = entries['runner'][row].get()
        course = entries['course'][row].get()
        start_time = entries['start_time'][row].get()
        finish_time = entries['finish_time'][row].get()
        print(f"{runner}, {course}, {start_time}, {finish_time}")

for row in range(1, 10):
    runner_var = tk.StringVar()
    runner_entry = ttk.Entry(window, textvariable=runner_var)
    runner_entry.grid(row=row, column=0, padx=10, pady=5)
    entries['runner'].append(runner_var)

    course_var = tk.StringVar()
    course_entry = ttk.Entry(window, textvariable=course_var)
    course_entry.grid(row=row, column=1, padx=10, pady=5)
    entries['course'].append(course_var)

    start_time_var = tk.StringVar()
    start_time_entry = ttk.Entry(window, textvariable=start_time_var)
    start_time_entry.grid(row=row, column=2, padx=10, pady=5)
    entries['start_time'].append(start_time_var)

    finish_time_var = tk.StringVar()
    finish_time_entry = ttk.Entry(window, textvariable=finish_time_var)
    finish_time_entry.grid(row=row, column=3, padx=10, pady=5)
    entries['finish_time'].append(finish_time_var)

submit_button = tk.Button(window, text="Submit", command=get_user_input)
submit_button.grid(row=14, column=0, columnspan=2, pady=10)

window.mainloop()
```